# A toy needs 3 batteries, but I only have 2 batteries

Tags: real

[image]

I have a boy, he has a toy which need 3 batteries, but I only have 2 batteries. With an easy hack I can switch on the toy to work properly. What did I do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a puzzle

Comment: This is a perfectly appropriate
[`real`](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/real/info)
puzzle, quite in line with many others tagged the same.
The tag's meaning has evolved (see, for instance, Meta post [_Real tag adjustment_](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4669/real-tag-adjustment)) and its short description could still be improved significantly.
Puzzles from the wild, like this one, make valuable contributions to this site,
especially toward authenticity in the pursuit of understanding all kinds of puzzles.
This puzzle's being put on hold dismays me.

Comment: @humn, well, this puzzle deserves a place, but in https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com I feel.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay Considering how the accepted answer is unlikely to work properly, this looks to be a barebones lateral thinking puzzle rather than a practical "life hack".

Comment: Also, @MeaCulpaNay, this is a site for puzzles in general, not just for puzzles that have no place anywhere else. How is this puzzle not puzzling?

Comment: I believe it's very important to include open-ended problems and riddles like this in Puzzling. There's a certain kind of mentality which doesn't like uncertainty and the reflex is to close off some problems which appear threatening. I would urge those with such urges :) to just relax and enjoy the diversity of keeping this kind of problem along with all the other more bounded problems. After all, as the wise Zen riddle asks, what is the sound of one hand clapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you:

> Directly connect one of the terminals to the opposite terminal with a strip of metal?

Problem:

> This could potentially not give the toy enough power, stopping it from working.

Comment: Did you solve this and vote to close or leave closed?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the tag for this question,

> Use a small, reasonably shaped **potato** / similar root vegetable(s) and join them with external wires to have the required power of 3 batteries.

Comment: good answer, but not an easy hack.